# Need ideas for securing a JMS based server process and database

Tags: security, jms

I have a tool that is distributed freely as an Eclipse plugin, which means that I can't track who uses it or ask them to register.

Every client tool communicate via a JMS broker with a single shared server process (written in Java) and can receive messages in reply. The server connects via Hibernate to a MySQL database.

At present, the only message that the tool sends is a request for data, and the server gets the message and sends a bulk of XML data representing elements to the client, which displays corresponding items in the IDE. Hence, I don't think that there is much that can be done to the server except a DoS attack.

Now, however, I want to add the following functionality: a user can assign a rating to a particular element (identified by a numeric id), and a message will be sent to the server which will store the rating as an event in a rating event table. When next requests for data come in, the average rating for each item will be sent with the request.

**My problem is that I've never deployed a tool that used a public server like this, even if it is hidden by the JMS broker. What attacks could be deployed against me and how can I defend against them?**

There's the problem of DoS, and I'm not sure how to address it.

There's the possibility of injection, but all my data is numeric and I don't know how hibernate deals with things.

There's the problem of spam or dummy-voting, and I can't really think of how to address that.

I'm sure there are others...

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the dummy voting, this is not secure (i.e. it wouldn't be acceptable for electoral purposes!) but it is a simple mechanism:

Create a GUID on the server, store it in an appropriate table and send to client. When client votes, it sends back the GUID, which is compared to the Database. If the GUID is valid, accept the vote and remove the DB stored GUID.